# keep external process running after exit

Tags: go, goland

How do you keep a process running after main exit?

**Update**: It turns out it is only when you are running in goland. The accepted answer including comments solved this.

Info: I have an executable that watches a folder for changes, and I need to start it from go and keep it running after exit.

I have see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42471349/how-to-keep-subprocess-running-after-program-exit-in-golang) but it does not solve the problem of running the process after exit.

```
package main

import "os/exec"

func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("sh", "long_running process", "&")
    cmd.Start()
}
fmt.Println("Sleeping...")
time.Sleep(8 * time.Second) // I can see the process running
```

Afterwards when I do "ps" the process is killed with the main application.

Comment: If you place a long `Time.Sleep` are you able to verify the long running process is running using ps?

Comment: Thanks, yes I can verify the process is running.

Comment: Goland is probably killing the process group. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35433741/in-golang-prevent-child-processes-to-receive-signals-from-calling-process/35435038#35435038

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't recreate the issue you are having. When I run the `sleep` command and the goroutine terminates, it is still running when I search for it with `ps`

#### Update

1. Doesn't work running it with the debugger in GoLand.
2. **Except** if you enable run as `sudo` in the debug options window.
3. Without `sudo`: either with `go run`, or with `dlv debug` or **without** the debugger in GoLand.

```golang
package main

import (
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("sleep", "99999999")
    cmd.Start()
}
```

```
~/tempgo/process
▶ go run process.go

~/tempgo/process
▶ ps -ax | grep "sleep"
29907 ttys002    0:00.00 sleep 99999999
29925 ttys002    0:00.00 grep --color=auto --exclude-dir=.bzr --exclude-dir=CVS --exclude-dir=.git --exclude-dir=.hg --exclude-dir=.svn --exclude-dir=.idea --exclude-dir=.tox sleep

~/tempgo/process
```

Comment: Thanks but nope, the "sleep" application is gone with the exit of main. I will update my question using "sleep".

Comment: Are you running it via the debugger? (or via Goland or VS code?)

Comment: Bouth with and without the debugger attached in goland. Hmm good question, I will try outside goland...

Comment: It doesn't work in Goland...  `go run...` from the terminal works.

Comment: Any explaination to why goland won't allow this to work?

Comment: @aclowkay that I am not sure about. When you run/debug it with delve via the terminal it works correctly.

Comment: @aclowkay This is the only other info I could find https://forum.golangbridge.org/t/trying-not-to-kill-linux-process-started-in-go/17535/5

Comment: It works with the goland debugger AND run as sudo. Not an ideal solution though.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue with/without sudo and debugger inside GoLand (2021.1 Beta 3). What GoLand version are you using (`Help | About`)?

Comment: GoLand 2019.2.5

Comment: Thanks. Please use the latest release version or try out our [Beta 3 version](https://www.jetbrains.com/go/nextversion/). We slightly change implementation in the newer versions and it should work as expected (spawn a process in the background) without sudo.